# Conflicting Jquery scripts

Tags: jquery, scripting, conflict

I've got three different jquery scripts running on my page, I think using different versions of jquery, which will not all work at the same time. I've tried using noconflict to no avail- I imagine the answer is very simple and the code is a mess, but I'm very new to Jquery so cant spot it. I've tried getting rid of various bits, and one of the three always stops working, as it is at the moment only the forward and back buttons on the slideshow, which is the last block of code (entitled 'camera') are not working, but the dropdown menu and 'squares' are. Thanks in advance for your help. Here is the code:

```
          <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > 
            <title>AMAR </title> 
            <meta name="description" content="AMAR"> 
                  <link rel='stylesheet' id='camera-css'  href='css/camera.css' type='text/css' media='all'> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flexdropdown.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




          <script type="text/javascript" src="flexdropdown.js">

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="t

ext/javascript">google.load("jquery","1.6.1");</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jsquares.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <script src="js/jquery.hoverintent.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jsquares.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#js-container').jsquares();
    });
    </script>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/camera.min.js'></script> 

        <script>
            jQuery(function(){

                jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
    height: '40%',
                    thumbnails: false,
    fx: 'simpleFade', hover: false, navigationHover: false, portrait: false, time: 8000, 

                });

                jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
                    height: '30%',
                    loader: 'bar',
                    pagination: false,
                    thumbnails: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So inexplicably, it seems to be something to do with the height of the wrapper? All the scripts are now running fine along-side each other fine, but when I increase the height of the wrapper, the next and prev buttons on the camera slideshow stop working, no idea why.