# Conflicting JQuery/Javascript Scripts

Tags: jquery

I am using an image slider that comes with its own javascript libraries and script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Slider/Scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Slider/Scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Slider/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Slider/Scripts/camera.min.js'></script>
<script>
        jQuery(function(){

            jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                thumbnails: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

but at the same time I am using a script that resizes my content div so to fit the window size:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){
$(window).resize(function(){
   var height = $(this).height() - $("#Header").height() - $("#Footer").height()
   $('#Content').height(height);
})

$(window).resize(); //on page load
});
</script>
```

The bottom script works, however, as long as I have `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>`in my code (without which the bottom script won't work), the top script won't work, and the slider will not appear.

I have looked at previous (similar) questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674236/conflicting-jquery-scripts), which is caused by the same image slider, but I cant seem to find a solution. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue, I would appreciate it heaps.

Comment: Don't include your jQuery file in 2 locations. Load it once at the top of your page to ensure all javascript withing your document will use it.

Comment: They're (apparently) different files - without the first lot, the image slider won't work, and without the last inclusion, the resizing script won't work.

Comment: `jquery.min.js` is a jQuery file, no? If it is, check the version number. `.camera()` has a minimum required version of 1.4. If `jQuery.min.js` is earlier than that, it won't work

Comment: It is, it is version 1.7.1

Comment: Then get rid of the bottom jquery file, it's redundant and your bottom script isn't working due to another reason. If you call 2 jQuery files, they mess with each other and cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: But without the bottom file, the second script won't run. I think I found a solution though. I shoved the first portion of code at the end of my page, and this seems to have resolved my issues. If anyone does have a reason for this though, I would still appreciate if you could comment or answer.

Comment: See above for the most likely reason

Comment: Thank you for your help. After a bit of playing around, it just 'fixed' itself to work with only one .js file, whereas before it would not work properly as if each file correlated to one particular script and both were required to operate both scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Loading multiple copies of jQuery onto a page can cause problems with your scripts.

The best practice is to load one copy of jQuery at the top of your page. This will mean all scripts and script files on the page will use it without any problems.